# Unloadable plugins leak assemblies in Mono

Tags: c#, .net, mono, appdomain

I'm implementing a plugin system which allows them to be reloaded without restarting the host process. Everything works flawlessly in .NET 4.5 but when running in Mono 3.2.7 the plugin assembly gets leaked into the host AppDomain and the plugin can not be changed.

The assembly gets loaded into the host AppDomain when calling `AppDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap` to create an instance of a type in the plugin assembly. This shouldn't cause problems because the type inherits `MarshalByRefObject` and shares a common interface.

You can see my code here: https://github.com/Rohansi/PluginTest The line which causes the assembly to leak is [here](https://github.com/Rohansi/PluginTest/blob/master/PluginTest/Plugin.cs#L76).

Comment: what do you mean with leak? memory leak?

Comment: The plugin assembly is loaded into the host AppDomain. When this happens you can't reload new versions of the plugin (it can crash depending on how much they differ).

Comment: if it crashes, please post the stacktrace of the crash

Comment: [Here is the output I get.](https://gist.github.com/Rohansi/24767cd8d339c1319471) There is no stacktrace for the segfault at the end. The program can still technically run but attempting to use anything from the broken plugin will cause issues.

Comment: ok, this seems to be a mono bug, please file it here with a minimal testcase: http://bugzilla.xamarin.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this issue. I've updated the Github repo with the fixes but I'll sum it up here.

To prevent leaking the assembly into the host AppDomain the assembly must not be in one of the locations the runtime will search for it. You either need to load it in a subdirectory or load it under a different file name. The assembly will no longer be automatically loaded into the host AppDomain but it started crashing when reloading.

I fixed this crash by replacing `CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap` calls with [this method](https://github.com/Rohansi/PluginTest/blob/6b5643eb4bd8f740dbbfca3c8b77a3ef48553823/PluginCommon/PluginBridge.cs#L30-L34). The PluginBridge instance is still created with `CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap`.

After all this it seems I have working plugin reloading in both .NET and Mono (tested in 3.4).